# hql in-clause with multiple hits in child collection

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, in-clause

I have a table/entity called `Recipe` with a child collection of type `Tag`.
I want to be able to find a Recipe searching by two or more tags. Something like:

```
SELECT re FROM Recipe re JOIN re.tags t WHERE t in :tagsIds
```

**but I only want those hits where the Tag collection contains all tagIds.**
Is it possible in HQL/SQL? (Maybe using Criteria?)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so this did it. Thanks for the replies.

```
String hql = "select r from Recipe r " +
                "join r.tags t " +
                "where t.id in (:tags) " +
                "group by r " +
                "having count(t)=:tag_count";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setParameterList("tags", tagIds);
query.setInteger("tag_count", tagIds.size());
List<Recipe> recipes = query.list();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have two different entities Recipe and Tag, it can be done as below.

```
    Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria("Recipe.class");
    criteria.createAlias("tags", "tag");
    criteria.add(Restrictions.in("tag.id", Arrays.asList(1,2,3)));
    return (List<Recipe>) criteria.list();
```

Comment: With this I get the same result as in my HQL example but every row comes twice. I still get hits on recipes that only have one of the tagIds.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may be missing parentheses in the HQL. It should be:

```
... WHERE t in (:tagsIds)
```

Comment: It actually works without the parenthesis. Maybe we are using different versions?